# Как реализовать отправку pdf файла на указанный е-майл?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на **WordPress** и форма с **contact form 7** где одно поле , `e-mail` адрес. Как сделать что бы при отправке формы, на указанный е-майл отправлялась письмо с `.pdf` файлом?

Comment: прикрепить pdf файл (P.S ваш кэп)

Comment: http://aimblog.ru/ustanovka/plaginy-wordpress/forma-obratnoj-svyazi-v-wordpress-plagin-contact-form-7-kak-prikrepit-fajl-captcha-kapcha.html

Comment: Прикол там ещё и в том, что надо прописать типы файлов, и максимальный размер